# C++ Operator "=" overload - Get all values in vector on lhs to equal a double value on rhs

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

I'm trying to overload the "="-operator in C++ but cannot get it working the way. My idea is to change all elements in a vector to equal a double value.

I've tried several ways but cannot get it work (getting different errors). Hope someone can give me some guidance. Below is where I'm stuck at now.

```
MyClass &operator=(const MyClass &lhs){
    for (int i = 0; i < lhs.vect.size(); i++){
        lhs.vect[i] = this;
    }
    return lhs;
};

int main() {
MyClassName = 3; // Should change all element in the vector to 3
};
```

Comment: The assignment operator is supposed to modify `*this`, not the argument. (The argument is the right-hand operand, so "lhs" is not a good name.)

Comment: Probably start with: `MyClass &operator=(const double rhs)` as the signature.  Not sure if this overload passes the _"least surprise"_ test.  I think it should be an ordinary method eg `MyClass::setall`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your prototype method for overloading the '=' operator, you are passing an reference to an object of MyClass class. If you want to pass a double, you need to change your prototype to

```
MyClass &operator=(double value);
```

Then you just have to assign value to all of the elements of your vector.

```
        MyClass &operator=(double value);
        {
            for (unsigned int i = 0; i < _v.size(); ++i)
                    _v[i] = value;
            return *this;
        }
```

(Where _v is the vector that your class contains)
Of course, you can create a method to copy all of the elements of a MyClass object into another MyClass object, but that's not the question.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the correct code:

```
class MyClass {
public:
    std::vector<double> vect;
    MyClass& operator=(double v) {
        for (int i = 0; i < vect.size(); i++) {
            vect[i] = v;
        }
        return *this;
    };
};
```

assignment operator declared as member of class the lhs -> this and the value assigned is rhs